# What could possibly be wrong in creating maven project if you have error in pom.xml file

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-services, jersey-1.0

missing artifact org.glassfish.extras glassfish-embedded-web:jar3.1.1 and there's an error in the pom.xml file of my maven project using jersey.

please explain what is wrong? the error mark is in the dependency tag below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
  <artifactsId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactsId>
  <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
<dependency>
```

And also there an error in annotations @Path, @GET, and @Produces of myResource.java class

Comment: What IDE do you use? Where have you put the version variable `glassfish.version`? Does your IDE automatically download and update those dependencies?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Java EE for Web Developers, Oxygen.3a Release 4.7.3a. When I change the version to 5.0.0, errors go away from the dependency tag but still shows there's an error in the file itself and when I open the xml file, there's no visible error. thanks

Comment: Have you defined the variable for the version number in the properties section of your pom.xml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

Right click -> Maven -> Update Project -> check "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" and then click ok.

Answer (score 3):

The error you have posted is`org.glassfish.extras glassfish-embedded-web:jar3.1.1`. There seems to be issue with the declared version part as it is coming as `jar3.1.1`. It should be `3.1.1` only.

Make sure you have `declared version correctly in the pom.xml` file for this dependency.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Java EE for Web Developers, Oxygen.3a Release 4.7.3a. When I change the version to 5.0.0, errors go away from the dependency tag but still shows there's an error in the file itself and when I open the xml file, there's no visible error. thanks

Answer (score -1):

${glassfish.version}  -> it mean you must define it. You can replace it with the version in mvn repository. 
it like "2.27". 
example :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-b06</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```